# Install oracle sample schema on a remote database

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

Is it possible to install Oracle Database 12c Sample schemas on a remote database that I have access?
I am trying to install sample schemas on AWS RDS service that I do not have SYSDBA access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If "install" means `create user ...`, then the answer is (sadly) *no*. Unless, of course, you provide login credentials which will connect you as a privileged user, the one that can create other users. You don't have to be a DBA. Here's an example:

Connected as SYS (which is a SYSDBA), I'm creating my own "sys" user which will then be granted a privilege to create other users:

```
SQL> connect sys@xe as sysdba
Enter password:
Connected.
SQL> create user my_sys identified by stacko
  2  default tablespace users
  3  temporary tablespace temp
  4  quota unlimited on users;

User created.

SQL> grant create session to my_sys;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> grant create user to my_sys;

Grant succeeded.
```

OK; now, connect as newly created user and create yet another one:

```
SQL> connect my_sys/stacko@xe
Connected.
SQL> create user test identified by test;

User created.

SQL>
```

It works.

Therefore, see if there's such a *powerful* user available to you (or, whether you can get it, somehow).

Once it is done, you'll be able to connect as that user and create all its objects. Of course, you'll have to grant it set of privileges, from `CREATE SESSION`, `CREATE TABLE`, etc. - depending on what you're going to do.

However, if you can't get it, I'm afraid that you won't be able to do that - not by yourself.

Comment: Install does not mean create user.  I am following the instructions from here https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/comsc/installing-sample-schemas.html#GUID-CB945E4C-D08A-4B26-A12D-3D6D688467EA

But it is prompting for the SYS user account credentials.

Comment: As far as I can tell, process on that page does **create user**. The fact that you don't see it doesn't mean it isn't there. If you open the mentioned .SQL script, you'll find that command. What do you think, why do you have to provide SYS password, default tablespace name, later on you're asked for the HR password ... - it is everything you can see in an example I posted previously.

Comment: @Littelefoot thanks for your response. I am trying to install Oracle sample schema and its objects ( HR for examples ) on a remote database. I do not have SYS account credentials.  But my user name (dba1) has all the necessary permissions to create schemas.  The  Manually Installing of the HR Schema in the https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/comsc/installing-sample-schemas.html#GUID-C0254DAB-F54C-4B20-9B1E-4F9E21781B96 
expects me to enter the credentials for SYS user.

Comment: If you have a script that creates all **objects** that originally belong to the HR schema, I suggest you skip the CREATE USER part and run only CREATE TABLE, CREATE VIEW, CREATE SEQUENCE and such. It means that you'll have HR's objects in your own schema; so what? As far as I understood, your main goal is to have tables and data to work with. It doesn't matter whether they belong to HR or you, does it?

Comment: That is correct. My goal is to create the schema and the sample data in any schema. I will see if I can extract the necessary scripts from the Oracle sample schema. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: You're welcome. That shouldn't be too difficult; it is a textual file you can edit in any editor, so just comment (or remove) unnecessary lines and run the rest of it. Good luck!